# How to By Pass CSRF token validation in ZAP Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, owasp, zap

I am new to OWASP ZAP, I have a login based authenticated web application. Login expects Username, Password and csrf token gets generated dynamically when I debugged in OWASP.
Now to allow the ZAP jenkins job to be successful how can I pass CSRF token in ZAP jenkins job?

I believe because of that I am getting below error -

```
[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SPIDER SCAN STATUS [ 0% ]
[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] ALERTS COUNT [ 0 ]

9117 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Starting spider...
9117 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Scan will be performed from the point of view of User: fred
9134 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-1] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.users.User  - Authenticating user: USER
9266 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-1] ERROR org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType  - Unable to prepare authentication message: Index: 0, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType$PostBasedAuthenticationMethod.extractParametersFromPostData(PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType.java:458)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType$PostBasedAuthenticationMethod.replaceAntiCsrfTokenValueIfRequired(PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType.java:420)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType$PostBasedAuthenticationMethod.authenticate(PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType.java:339)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.users.User.authenticate(User.java:265)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.users.User.processMessageToMatchUser(User.java:175)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:581)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:573)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:478)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:448)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.spider.SpiderTask.fetchResource(SpiderTask.java:445)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.spider.SpiderTask.runImpl(SpiderTask.java:218)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.spider.SpiderTask.run(SpiderTask.java:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
9270 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-1] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.users.User  - Authentication failed for user: USER
9326 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-2] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.users.User  - Authenticating user: USER
9389 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-2] ERROR org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType  - Unable to prepare authentication message: Index: 0, Size: 0
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType$PostBasedAuthenticationMethod.extractParametersFromPostData(PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType.java:458)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType$PostBasedAuthenticationMethod.replaceAntiCsrfTokenValueIfRequired(PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType.java:420)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType$PostBasedAuthenticationMethod.authenticate(PostBasedAuthenticationMethodType.java:339)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.users.User.authenticate(User.java:265)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.users.User.processMessageToMatchUser(User.java:175)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:581)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAuthenticated(HttpSender.java:573)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:478)
    at org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpSender.sendAndReceive(HttpSender.java:448)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.spider.SpiderTask.fetchResource(SpiderTask.java:445)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.spider.SpiderTask.runImpl(SpiderTask.java:218)
    at org.zaproxy.zap.spider.SpiderTask.run(SpiderTask.java:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
9391 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-2] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.users.User  - Authentication failed for user: USER
9438 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-2] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spidering process is complete. Shutting down...
9441 [ZAP-SpiderShutdownThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Spider scanning complete: true
```

Comment: Why do you want to bypass it? If this was possible, the whole concept of using a CSRF token was useless

Comment: Have you tried reproducing this via the ZAP Desktop? Its much easier to debug issues when you can see whats going on.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this in zap desktop. I get this only when i am running through Jenkins.

Comment: How have you configured the ZAP desktop? You will need to configure ZAP running in Jenkins in the same way. Are you using the same version of ZAP in both cases?

Comment: I have configured zap daemon on jenkins slave machine and run job on that slave machine. I fixed the issue by adding script based authentication instead form based. HOwever the spider scan shows 0% progress and authentication issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can (temporarily) disable CSRF with below groovy script. Go to `Manage Jenkins >> Script Console`, then execute the below groovy script.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def instance = Jenkins.instance
instance.setCrumbIssuer(null)
```